# Tri-State Close Button

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

In times past my team used React Bootstrap to power modals in our React app.  But we're dropping that library in favor of a custom built UI library.  As part of this change, I've built a custom Close Button that uses specially designed "X" images.  This "X" can display any one of three images at any given time:

1. Regular "X"
2. Hover-state "X"
3. Disabled "X"

It's working almost perfectly but there is one slight problem.  Here's the pertinent code in my React component:

```
<div className={getClasses()}
     data-testid={getDataTestId()}
     onClick={() => props.onClick()}
>
  <img className='close-icon'
       src={closeIcon}
       alt=''
  />
  <img className='close-icon-hover'
       src={hoverIcon}
       alt=''
  />
  <img className='close-icon-disabled'
       src={disabledIcon}
       alt=''
  />
</div>
```

FYI the div's `className` has two relevant style classes: `close-button` and `disabled`.  So these are all possible:

- `<div className='close-button'`
- `<div className='close-button:hover'`
- `<div className='close-button disabled'`
- `<div className='close-button:hover disabled'`

Here's the SCSS code I wrote to control the appearance of the X's:

```
.close-icon-hover,
.close-button:hover .close-icon,
.close-button .close-icon-disabled,
.close-button:hover .disabled .close-icon-hover,
.close-button:hover .close-icon-disabled,
.disabled .close-icon,
.disabled .close-icon-hover {
  display: none;
}
.disabled .close-icon-disabled {
  display:inline;
}
.close-button:hover .close-icon-hover {
  display: inline;
}
```

Everything works perfectly now except for one thing: When `disabled` is present the `hoverIcon` still appears when the mouse hovers over top.  I would have expected that the 4th SCSS line above to prevent the hover icon from appearing but it does not:

```
.close-button:hover .disabled .close-icon-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

There's clearly a flaw in my SCSS logic but I haven't been able to spot it yet.  Might anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing of classes inside an element, for example your:

```
<div className='close-button disabled'>
```

Is different to the spacing of classes inside css, for example your:

```
.close-button:hover .disabled .close-icon-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

The above is saying, inside an element with the class `.close-button`, is a 2nd element with the class `.disabled`, and then inside it, is a third element with `.close-icon-hover`.

Which would mean a 3 layer structure. I think what you want to do is this:

`.close-button.disabled` (meaning, the disabled class is also present for that same element) and only then, add `:hover` after that, like this:

```
.close-button.disabled:hover .close-icon-hover {}
```

In a CSS selector, a space denotes a jump in hierarchy, say, from parent to child. Inside an element's class attribute, css clases need spaces between them to above being grouped and interpreted as a single entity :)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I need to revisit the SCSS docs to confirm that this is the case for it.

Comment: more than anything particular about SCSS, SASS, LESS or whatever, it's the logic behind CSS itself. I hope this worked for you :)